# Troubleshooting SAML with HTTP Dumping

Tags: saml

I am trying to troubleshoot and understand SAML for a government citizenship authentication. I can only use SAML Tracer, Firebug or Fiddler.

There are a few steps:
1. User gets directed from website to Service Provider. 
2. Service Provider creates a HTML form with **partner_id** and sends this to Identity Provider.
3. Identity Provider shows login page. User logins on Identity Provider with mobile SMS OTP.
4. Identity Provider authenticates and sends **Assertion** back to Service Provider website.
5. Service Provider displays the right webpage after authentication.

I want to tell, what exactly happens at step 2. 
For step 4, I can see the Assertion in the dump. But there is a lot of garbage string before that.
At step 5. when the **partner_id** was not sent, there displayed webpage at step 5 will be an error message. Is there anyway I can tell this error display from the HTTP request? (I suppose this will be hard to answer.)

Comment: I see this in the dump , is this the assertion?<t:TokenType>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:assertion</t:TokenType>

Comment: "here is a lot of garbage string before that" - is that a signature maybe? You are right, this is hard to answer without details. And it's not clear which trouble you're trying to shoot.

Comment: Description of step 2 suggests that HTTP POST Binding is used, so it's actually pretty/somewhat clear what happens there when you look at  the SAMLv2 core spec and the SAMLv2 bindings spec. Even step 4 is well defined when you look at the spec. Depending of the chosen binding the rseponse  can be signed or the assertion has to be signed

Comment: A way to rephrase my question, SAML does not take in 3rd party / external variables like the abovementioned partner_id right? It is purely for login authentication with no exchange of 3rd party values.